# How to Get the Meeting Details from MS Outlook when the meeting window is Opened using Apple script

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I am trying to execute a Apple script on MS Outlook  calendar to get the meeting details like "Date &Time ", Time zone and other stuff.

I can able to get the require details when the meeting invite is closed and then selected  but when the same invite is opened then i couldn't able to get any details from the apple script.

can some one please suggest me what exactly i need to do to get the required details.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    if (count of (windows whose index is 1)) is not 0 then
        set olObject to object of item 1 of (windows whose index is 1)
        if class of olObject is calendar event then
            set thisEvent to olObject
            get timezone of thisEvent
            get start time of thisEvent
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks !!Below is the Apple script which i'm trying to execute when the meeting window is opened but unfortunately no result is displayed when i execute.Please help me out.tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
 set selectedItems to selection
 repeat with theItem in selectedItems
  set props to properties of theItem
  repeat with proppp in props
  end repeat
  set vcard_data to (icalendar data of props)
  set vcard_extension to ".ics"
  set content of theItem to vcard_data as string 
  set theStart to start time of theItem
  display dialog exchange id of theItem as string
 end repeat
end tell

Comment: @Kishore - sorry - I don't quite understand your comment.  The answer I gave works for me if the meeting window is opened.  Is that the case for you?

Comment: @Kishore - please don't post multiple lines of code in comments.  If this is an update to the question, please edit the question.  Otherwise if it is a new question, then post a new question.

Comment: Thanks!! the script which you provided is very much help ful to resolve the issue which i'm facing.  Thank you so much again.